# Multiple instances of the same spring batch job running in each thread with different params

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Using spring batch/spring boot, is it possible to have a spring batch job with reader, processor, and writer being started as a job multiple times per thread with different `jobparameters`?

My use case:

I have a number of various folders that I need to watch.
If new files enters a folder I need to invoke the job
and lock the folder while job is processing.

So this can happen for a various number of folders so that's why
I need the multiple instances of a spring batch job but with different `jobparameters` each time.

One job instance per folder and the number of folders can vary.
Anyone know if its even possible with spring batch, or should invent it myself?
I tried with spring batch job but it's always saying:

> A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[feedfiletransformer-delegate-job]

Comment: Paramaterize it correctly, also do you really need job running, you might want to combine it with Spring Integration which can detect new files and kickoff a batch job.

Comment: yes, I looked into this too, but I also need to be able to tie down my setup sometimes, so I think its safer to have a main job waking up and scan the folders. Because if the events already had happen the job will not catch up and this could be the case when service window is open.

Comment: Then simply stop the file poller and start when you are up again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by reading this post [mkyoung](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-a-job-instance-already-exists-and-is-complete-for-parameters/)

```
JobParameters jobParameters = 
          new JobParametersBuilder()
          .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
```

Comment: imho a bad one, just add the file instead the time. That way you still have a unique job for a single file. You should parameterize what you need. Split your jobs in 2 (or use Spring Integration as suggested), one for scanning the files and start a new job per file.

Comment: yes I am doing the last mentioned. But I struggled with: A job execution for this job is already running. But you mean that it will work without the time uniqueness and instead can distinguish on jobparameters?

Comment: You should add the name of the file you are processing (assuming the name of the file is unique each time you execute a new job).

Comment: yes I will :) above its just to see that I can have multiple instances of a job running. the filenames will be added too. Thx a lot for helping me